# Alternating between even and odd elements in Array with GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm trying to work with more GUI stuff but I'm having problem with something.  I have an array of JLabels.  Each of them contain 1 number from 0 to 7.  I'm making the numbers "light up" by changing the background color from black to green.  Is there any way to make all the even numbers "light up" while keeping all the odd numbers dark and then vice versa?  I tried using a timer but my algorithm isn't working as it should.  Below is the code for the method that configures the timer.  Thanks

```
    public void configureAlternatingTimer() {
    if (this.timer != null) {
        this.timer.stop();
    }

    this.timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
                    lights[1].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[3].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[5].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[7].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[i].setBackground(Color.green);
                }
                if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7) {
                    lights[0].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[2].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[4].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[6].setBackground(Color.black);
                    lights[i].setBackground(Color.green);
                }
                if(i==8) {
                    return;
                }
            }

        }

    });
    this.timer.start();

}
```

Also, I'm trying to simulate a "larson scanner" which would light up to 7 then go back down to 0 then repeat.  I can get it to go from 0 to 7 it's just the going back down part that I'm having trouble with.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `for-loop`, it's preventing the Event Dispatching Thread from processing `repaint` requests

Instead, each time that the `actionPerformed` method is called, update some kind of counter and then take action on it, for example...

```
this.timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    private int sequence = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (sequence % 2 == 0) {
            lights[1].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[3].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[5].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[7].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[sequence].setBackground(Color.green);
        } else {
            lights[0].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[2].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[4].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[6].setBackground(Color.black);
            lights[sequence].setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        
        sequence++;
        if (sequence > 7) {
            // This seems to be important...?
        }
    }
});
```

**Updated based on comments**

This should show all odds or all evens...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    private int sequence = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(sequence + "; " + (sequence % 2));

        for (int index = 0; index < lights.length; index++) {

            if (index % 2 == 0 && sequence % 2 == 0 || index % 2 != 0 && sequence % 2 != 0) {
                lights[index].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                lights[index].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }

        }

        sequence++;
        if (sequence > 7) {
            sequence = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok.  Where should I initialize my i, and should I just increment it after each if-statement?

Comment: Check the update, I called it `sequence`.  I've chosen to increment after the `if` statements, but there's no reason why you can't increment before hand, you'll just lose `0`

Comment: Ok, I like it so far.  Should I change my lights[i] call in both of them lights[sequence], because once it hits 8 how can I reset it to continue?

Comment: See that last `if` statement...you could either rest the `sequence` there or stop the timer based on your needs...

Comment: Well the way I have the GUI set up that the process should run until another button is clicked.  I think I would like to reset it.  I don't know how to reset it.  I tried: 'sequence==8' 'sequence=0' but it still passes the else condition so I was thrown an out of bounds error.

Comment: Assuming you only have 8 elements in the array, then the `if` statement should actually look like `if (sequence > 7)`

Comment: Ok, This is going to sound weird, but instead of lighting up all the even ones then lighting up all the odd ones, the program is lighting them up in order from 0 to 7 then starting over again.  While I'll have to remember this code in the future, do you know how to get the even and odd ones to alternate?

Answer (score 0):

To determine if you have an even or odd number, you should think about using modulus operator % to determine if a number is odd or even. The modulus will return the remainder of a number after it has been divided.

```
For example:
    4 / 2 = 2r0
    5 / 2 = 2r1
    6 / 2 = 3r0
    7 / 2 = 3r1
    so on and so forth...

if(i % 2 == 0) {
    // even
} else {
    // odd
}
```